# How to bind onclik event to call a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to bind a function when someone check the checkbox.

I've this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g6bjru7/) it works fine, but I've the same code and it's not working.

I've used CDNs for JQuery and Bootstrap, hope that there is no issue with that.

In the code below even is not binding perfectly and I didn't see any alert, although the same code works perfectly fine in the fiddle mentioned.

**HTML CODE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap FILES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- font awesome for the icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" id='mark' name='mark'>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="mark"]', function() {
      // when the checkbox is checked then do the following
      alert('thanks for checkcing me');

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

what is wrong with this code? if not, then why I'm not getting any kind of alert when I check the checkbox.
Please help, thanks !

Comment: The code is working fine. Its alerting

Comment: code works fine.

Comment: check the snippet your posted  code also worked.check any error on your `console.log`

Comment: I'm explaining the same thing that the fiddle code works fine, but the one I've posted(although that is same to the fiddle) it is not alerting !

Comment: Check the jquery is loaded or not

Comment: That's why I've included some CDNs , so that I'm loading them fine , according to the rules

Comment: how can I check either JQuery is loaded or not ?

Comment: Ensure JS is not disabled, due to any browser restrictions, of local files.

Comment: The page where I've this checkbox is actually loaded via AJAX, so can that be a problem ? @maheer Ali

Answer (score 2):

Check the jquery loaded:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log("jQuery is not loaded");  // Or
    alert("jQuery is loaded");  
} else {
    console.log("jQuery is not loaded");
    alert("jQuery is not loaded"); 
}
```